# Timer.cancel() not functioning

Tags: android, sqlite, timertask

I want to stop it when it reaches the maximum item but it crashes.

This is my java class where I want to display the images.

```
     public void start(View button) {
    if (timer != null) {
        timer.cancel();
    }
    position = 0;
    i=0;
    j=1;
    k=0;
    startSlides();
}

    public void startSlides() {
    timer = new Timer();
    timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {

        public void run() {
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {

                    Intent intent = getIntent();
                    int topicId = intent.getIntExtra("SelectedTopicId", 1);

                    databaseAccess.open();

                    List<byte[]> data = databaseAccess.getImage(topicId);

                    Bitmap image = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(data.get(position), 0, data.get(position).length);

                    imageView.setImageBitmap(image);
                    position++;

                    List<String> vocab = databaseAccess.getVocabName(topicId);
                    textView2.setText(vocab.get(k));
                    k++;

                    databaseAccess.close();

                    if (position == data.get(position-1).length -1) {
                        timer.cancel();
                    }
                }
            });
        }

    }, 0, 1000);
}
```

This is the error:

> FATAL EXCEPTION: main Process: com.example.user.displayvocab, PID:
>     15550 java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 6, Size: 6 at
>     java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:411) at
>     com.example.user.displayvocab.Choice$1$1.run(Choice.java:100) at
>     android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751) at
>     android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) at
>     android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154) at
>     android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6692) at
>     java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1468)
>     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1358)

I have been looking for solutions and I still haven't figured out how to solve it.

Comment: position++; is misplaced

Comment: where should i place it?

Comment: You are getting the IndexOutOfBoundsException meaning you are accessing the index that does not exist and you have not provided the information about the position.

Comment: I have edited, please check. When i press on Start button, it should starts display images and stops when reaches the last image. How should I do that to fix the IndexOutOfBoundsException error? Thanks

Comment: shouldn't you be checking the length of the data list object? for what I can see every object inside data is a byteArray of a bitmap, so you are checking the position against the length of the array. It should be something like `if (position == data.length -1)` ?